# http ResponseWriter duplicate answer golang

Tags: http, go, httpresponse

```
func main() {

  http.HandleFunc("/", foo)

  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func foo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  s:= "name"

  fp := path.Join("templates", "index.html")

  tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(fp)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  if  err := tmpl.Execute(w, s); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Println("successfull Operation!!")

}
```

This code displays 2 "successfull Operation!!" but when I add `/home` (`http.HandleFunc("/home", foo)`), it doesn't. I want to know why it displays "successfull Operation!!" twice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you specify where *exactly* you have to add `/home (http.HandleFunc("/home", foo))` to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: Just log what the requests are, and you'll see what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because modern browsers send an extra request for `/favicon.ico` which is also handled in your `/` request handler.

If you ping your server with `curl` for example, you'll see only one request being sent:

```
 curl localhost:3000
```